# Оптимизация решения

Tags: java, оптимизация

Суть задачи: нужно найти все числа в диапазоне start-end, которые возможно разложить на k простых множителей. Написанный код справляется со своей задачей, но это происходит за очень большое время. Собственно вопрос в том как можно сократить время выполнения задачи.

```
class Kata {
public static long[] countKprimes(int k, long start, long end) {

    ArrayList<Long> answer = new ArrayList<>();

    int count = 0;

    /*Собственно цикл который все это выполняет*/
    for (long i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        long temp = i;
        long mult = 2;

            while (count < k){
                if (temp % mult == 0) {count++; temp = temp / mult; continue;}
                if (mult > i || (mult > 2 && mult % 4 == 0)) break;
                else if(mult == 2) mult++;
                else mult += 2;
            }
            if (temp == 1 && count == k){answer.add(i);}
            count = 0;
        }

      /*Перенос полученной коллекции в массив*/
        long[] ans = new long[answer.size()];
        int m = 0;
        for(long i:answer) {ans[m] = i; m++;}
        return ans;
    }
}
```

Comment: интересно, за какое время оно делает свою работу? задание звучит как очень тяжелое для современных и неквантовых компьютеров

Comment: @dgzargo например мой ноутбук такой поиск от 0 до 1000000 при k=5 выполняет за неизвестное кол-во времени(мне просто надоедает ждать), так что мне ваш сарказм не совсем понятен. В духе "не проверял, но осуждаю".

Comment: все намного хуже: проверял и осуждаю. я не разбирался в логике вашего метода, но думаю что там какой-то вид перебора. этот способ не может быть эффективным. посмотрите статью вики [Факторизация целых чисел](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB)

Comment: идея оптимизации в том чтоб хранить предыдущие подсчитанные значения в виде 4->2, 5->1, 8-> 4, и по ним находить более высокие разложения, например 5*2 =10, 2  множителя, 8*2. 16, 8 множителей. сокращённо посчитай степени двойки и комбинации из их сумм например 8 +4  = (4+2)*2

Comment: может задачу можно упростить и не делать таких вычислений?

Comment: Что такое в вашем понимание "простой множитель"?

Comment: @rjhdby Простые множители (простые делители) положительного целого числа — это простые числа, которые делят это число нацело (без остатка). И если честно я не знаю как может быть в такой точной науке как математика "мое понимание".

Comment: @АлександрКочуров просто в вашем решении я не вижу простых чисел, потому и спросил. Либо они настолько хитро запрятаны, что поверхностный взгляд их не находит. Для начала разнесите логику проверки целочисленного деления и получение простых чисел.

Comment: @rjhdby изначально берется первое простое число - 2, и проверяется делится ли нацело текущее число на него. Если да то делится и процесс повторяется, если нет то в случае с двойкой прибавляется 1, в остальных случаях прибавляется 2, и таким образом идет перебор всех простых чисел.

Comment: @АлександрКочуров вы в курсе, что "простые" и "нечетные" - это совершенно разные понятия?

Comment: @rjhdby вы в курсе, что каждое новое "простое" число(после 3) находится на расстоянии 2n от предыдущего, то есть в том числе является нечетным. Так что расскажите мне поподробнее об совершенной разности этих двух понятий.

Comment: Вероятно, товарищ намекает на то, что избыточность алгоритма поиска простых чисел вы множите на количество внешних итераций..

Comment: @АлександрКочуров да, все простые, кроме 2, являются нечетными, но из этого совершенно не следует, что все нечетные являются простыми

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не замудренное, читабельное, работающее быстрее чем мой изначальный код решение.

```
public class KPrimes {

public static long nPrime(long n) {
    int result = 0;
    for (long i = 2 ; i < Math.sqrt(n)+1 ; ++i) {
        while (n%i == 0) {
            result++;
            n /= i;
        }
    }
    if (n > 1) result++;
    return result;
}
public static long[] countKprimes(int k, long start, long end) {
    return LongStream.range(start,end+1).filter(x -> nPrime(x)==k).toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (temp % mult == 0) {count++; temp = temp / mult; mult = 2; continue;}
```

Зачем mult присваивать 2? Вы же все числа до mult уже перебрали.

```
if (mult > i || (mult > 2 && mult % 4 == 0)) break;
```

mult > i можно заменить на mult*mult > i. Если нет делителей до корня квадратного, то их и после не будет.

UPD: можно заменить даже не на mult* mult > i, а на mult*mult > temp. Это еще больше сократит кол-во итераций.

Comment: И еще, я бы сперва составил список всех простых от 2 до корня из end и перебирал бы их, а не все нечетные натуральные подряд.

Comment: Действительно, присваивание было излишним, но не потому что все числа были перебраны, а из-за continue которое не давало этой переменной увеличиваться при нахождении нужной пары число-делитель, а новый цикл for так и так ее возвращал на 2. Если проверять от 2 до корня из end то результат не верный, например если проверять от 0 до 100, то в случае с числом 46 выходит что: sqrt(100)=10; 46/2=23; и так как 23 простое число, но мы ограничены 10, то цикл просто не дойдет до нужного числа.

Comment: @АлександрКочуров, что мешает вам проверить остаток после цикла, и, если он не 1, добавить его как последний простой множитель?

Comment: про корень и Ваш пример, если у числа нет простых делителей до корня из числа, то оно простое, В вашем случае это 23. Значит 23 - это и есть последний простой делитель.

Comment: @АлександрПоташев корень тут не подходит.

Comment: @vp_arth возможно то что например 16/2=8, 8!=1, и по вашей логике получается что 8 становится простым множителем, коим она не является.

Comment: Что за ересь вы тут пишете? А дальше на 2 кто делить будет? Дошли до корня, цикл закончился - тогда и проверяйте остаток

Answer (score 1):

Единицу отбрасываем, в виду нелепости ее использования в данной задаче. (я бы и 2 отбросил кстати)

Для начала вычисляем верхнюю границу допустимых для данных условий простых. Для этого берем `k-1` простых, начиная с 2 и по очереди делим на них `end`

```
Double max = end;
for(int i=0; i<k-1; i++) max = max / getPrime(i);
```

Потом определяем нижнюю границу, для которой любые комбинации простых меньше нее 
не попадут в заданный диапазон

```
Long minPrime = (Long) Math.pow(start, 1.0 / k);
```

Потом находим все простые числа в диапазоне от 2 до maxPrime

Дальше перебираем все возможные комбинации из `k` этих простых, перемножаем и отбрасываем те, которые меньше `start`, либо больше `end`.

Вариантов перебора достаточно много, но я бы посмотрел в сторону работы с битовыми масками, в качестве бонуса они дадут возможность сразу отбросить все комбинации, дающие результат меньше `start`.

Примерный код работы с простыми

```
ArrayList<Long> primeNumbers = new ArrayList();

private Long getPrime(int index){
    while(primeNumbers.size() < index){
        primeNumbers.add(findNextPrime());
    }
    return primeNumbers[index];
}

private Long findNextPrime(){
  //  ищем нечетное число, больше максимального из primeNumbers,
  //  которое не делится ни на одно уже находящееся в этом массиве
}
```

PS Один из главных показателей хорошего кода заключается в том, сторонний человек, читая код сверху вниз, может понять, что он делает. В вашем случае это не так.

Answer (score 0):

Оптимизировать данное решение лучше всего сменой алгоритма :)

Мне в голову пришёл следующий вариант:

- берём набор чисел от `start` до `end`, каждому назначаем число - счётчик найденных делителей (инициализируем нулём)
- берём набор простых чисел от `2` до `end`
- для каждого такого простого числа `p`:

  - перебираем степени `m` числа `p` от `1` до `k+1`:

    - для каждого тестируемого числа от `start` до `end`, которое делится на `p^m`, увеличиваем счётчик на 1
- вернуть в качестве результата все числа от `start` до `end`, у которых счётчик оказался равным `k`

Вызов Вашей реализации `countKPrimes(6, 34657, 49894)` на моём компьютере отрабатывает 45 сек. Моя же реализация отрабатывает за долю секунды :)

Поскольку задача похожа на учебную, то полный код своего решения не привожу. Но дам подсказку, как оптимальнее обрабатывать числа, делящиеся на `p^m`.

Естественно, перебирать все числа от `start` до `end` неоптимально, нужно найти в диапазоне от `start` до `end` первое число, которое будет делиться на `p^m`, и затем от него идти по числам до `end` с шагом `p^m`.

Поскольку число `p^m` может быть достаточно велико, то поиск первого кратного ему числа простым перебором будет неоптимальным. Здесь тоже можно оптимизировать. Для этого возьмём остаток от деления `start` на `p^m`, и если остаток `r` не равен нулю, то увеличиваем число `start` на величину `(p^m - r)` - это и будет первое кратное `p^m` в тестируемом диапазоне.

Comment: Будет ли считать так же быстро если start - 0, end - 6000000(6 миллионов)?

Comment: У меня 7 сек. отрабатывает, включая генерацию простых чисел. Насколько это быстро или медленно, лучше познавать в сравнении с другими алгоритмами.